# SP2010 domain user migration problem

Tags: user-profile, migration

I have a rather basic SP2010 installation. 1xWFE, 1xSQL (2008) both on 2008 server.  When the original synchronization connection was created the forrest root was entered in FQDN form i.e. "domaina.net" rather than domainb.  The problem is SP doesn't seem to have liked the ".net" part and dropped it so now all users, managers, etc are now set as domaina\user rather than domaina.net\user or domainb\user.  As domaina<>domainb (though domaina.net resolves to domainb) it means that domaina\user does not resolve creating all sorts of issues, particularly in the organisation browser in My Sites.  As each user logs on it does correct itself, however I need this fixed before the site goes "live" and people start logging on.  The old STSADM tool seems to fix the problem with "stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin domaina\user -newlogin DOMAINB\user -ignoresidhistory".  However with nearly 2000 users I want to script this.  I am unable to gain an accurate list of profiles via AD so I would like to do this via a list of all the profiles in SP.  Can anyone tell me how to script this? I've looked into get-spuser however it seems to only show the users who have logged in and not the profiles created via the AD sync. I've spent 2 days looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful [MOSS profile update PowerShell script](http://blog.isaacblum.com/2010/01/21/powershell-bulk-update-moss-profile/) that might be a good starting point.